# Try and create on exception in Python

Tags: python, try-except

Python developers say that *it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*. Every time I can I follow that idea in my scripts. However I've arrived to situations where I don't know how to do that properly.

Let's say that you have a database of objects and you need to do stuff to those objects. When getting objects from the database it may happen that the object does not exist, so I decide to create it right there. Suppose further that the method for creating objects in database does not return the created object. The problem I have is that I'm repeating the code for getting the object:

```
try:
    obj = get_obj(name="foo")
except DoesNotExists:
    create_obj(name="foo")
    obj = get_obj(name="foo")
do_stuff(obj)
```

Is there a way as to avoid the duplication of code?

Comment: Why not just work with the newly created object and persist it to the database later?

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but: In general you'll want to be careful with lazy object creation like this (or at least make it a very conscious decision). It's easy to cause **writes-on-read** like this, which  can become a major pain later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling get_obj() directly, create a helper function named get_or_create_obj().

This function returns the specified object if it already exists, otherwise it creates it and then returns it.

If you care whether or not the object was found or created, the function can return a tuple of (created_flag, object).

Your get_or_create_obj() still has code duplication, but only in the one spot.

Comment: Useful precision : in Django, calling `MyModel.objects.get_or_create(arg=value)` return `(object, created_flag)`, not `(created_flag, object)`

Comment: Yes, the object should probably be the first item in the tuple.

Comment: The idea was to avoid code duplication **at all**, but I guess that's not possible without further complicating the code(e.g. wrapping everything with a `while True` and `break` later).

Comment: You could call create_obj() first, catching and ignoring DuplicateObject exceptions, then call get_obj().  But that seems icky.